# Using ArcGIS Area Solar Radiation tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, parameters, model, solar-radiation

I tried using the tool multiple times and my result values should be around 2000-3000 W/m2/d. However my results reach up to 6000 W/m2/d.

I am using a raster with cell size 30 meters and WGS 1984 UTM 48N. Sky Size is set to 400, Diffuse model type to STANDARD_OVERCAST_SKY and Diffuse proportion to 0,5 (since this is the actual diffuse proportion in this area ).

All other parameters in the tool are kept with their standard value.

Does anyone have ideas how to fix this issue?